# Why are we using interface to set onClick for View Holders for recycler view in the MainActivity

Tags: java, android

I am going through a tutorial which is using the Recycler View to display a list of weather for each day for a week.
There are two classes which I am confused in:

> ForecastAdapter and MainActivity

Here is the code for the above two classes:

> ForecastAdapter.java

```
public class ForecastAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ForecastAdapter.ForecastAdapterViewHolder> {

    private String[] mWeatherData;
    final private ForecastAdapterOnClickListener mClickHandler;

    //Why do we need to create an interface here.
    public interface ForecastAdapterOnClickListener {
        void onClick(String weatherForDay);
    }

    public ForecastAdapter(ForecastAdapterOnClickListener forecastAdapterOnClickListener) {
        mClickHandler = forecastAdapterOnClickListener;
    }


    public class ForecastAdapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        public final TextView mWeatherTextView;

        public ForecastAdapterViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mWeatherTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_weather_data);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int adapterPosition = getAdapterPosition();
            String weatherForDay = mWeatherData[adapterPosition];

            //Why are we calling onClick from mClickHandler here. Why can't we just display Toast here. 
            mClickHandler.onClick(weatherForDay); 

            /*Why can't we just display the Toast from here like this:
              Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), weatherForDay, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            */
        }

    }


    @Override
    public ForecastAdapterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        Context context = viewGroup.getContext();
        int layoutIdForListItem = R.layout.forecast_list_item;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        boolean shouldAttachToParentImmediately = false;

        View view = inflater.inflate(layoutIdForListItem, viewGroup, shouldAttachToParentImmediately);
        return new ForecastAdapterViewHolder(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ForecastAdapterViewHolder forecastAdapterViewHolder, int position) {
        String weatherForThisDay = mWeatherData[position];
    forecastAdapterViewHolder.mWeatherTextView.setText(weatherForThisDay);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (null == mWeatherData) return 0;
        return mWeatherData.length;
    }


    public void setWeatherData(String[] weatherData) {
        mWeatherData = weatherData;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

> MainActivity.java

```
//Why are implementing ForecastAdapterOnClickListener here?
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ForecastAdapter.ForecastAdapterOnClickListener{

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private ForecastAdapter mForecastAdapter;

private TextView mErrorMessageDisplay;

private ProgressBar mLoadingIndicator;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_forecast);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_forecast);
    mErrorMessageDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_error_message_display);

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
            = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


    mForecastAdapter = new ForecastAdapter(this);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);


    mLoadingIndicator = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pb_loading_indicator);

    loadWeatherData();
}


private void loadWeatherData() {
    showWeatherDataView();

    String location = SunshinePreferences.getPreferredWeatherLocation(this);
    new FetchWeatherTask().execute(location);
}


@Override
public void onClick(String weatherForDay) {
    Context context = this;
    Toast.makeText(context, weatherForDay, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
}


private void showWeatherDataView() {
    mErrorMessageDisplay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}


private void showErrorMessage() {
    mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mErrorMessageDisplay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mLoadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
        if (params.length == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        String location = params[0];
        URL weatherRequestUrl = NetworkUtils.buildUrl(location);

        try {
            String jsonWeatherResponse = NetworkUtils
                    .getResponseFromHttpUrl(weatherRequestUrl);

            String[] simpleJsonWeatherData = OpenWeatherJsonUtils
                    .getSimpleWeatherStringsFromJson(MainActivity.this, jsonWeatherResponse);

            return simpleJsonWeatherData;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] weatherData) {
        mLoadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        if (weatherData != null) {
            showWeatherDataView();
            mForecastAdapter.setWeatherData(weatherData);
        } else {
            showErrorMessage();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecast, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
        mForecastAdapter.setWeatherData(null);
        loadWeatherData();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

The adapter, view holder and recycler view is working as expected. We are now supposed to implement Click Handling on the rows of the recycler view. Whenever a particular row is clicked, we are supposed to display a toast.

As you can see, we are implementing OnClickListener in the ForecastAdapterViewHolder and in the onClick function we are calling the onClick of the interface "ForecastAdapterOnClickListener". 
In the MainActivity.java, we are implementing this "ForecastAdapterOnClickListener" and then displaying the toast.

Why can't we just display the toast in the onClick that is defined for the "ForecastAdapterViewHolder" class. I have tried it and it works. What is the point of doing what is being done in the code?
Is there some advantage in setting the click listener like that?

Comment: I can do that. My question, is there some advantage in doing what is being done in the code?

Answer (score 1):

Because you'll have to display information afterwards and isn't role of ViewHolder neither Adapter. Activity/fragment must do that.
It's to keep your code organized.